# Jexl3 unsolvable property exception when using enum

Tags: jexl

This code used to work under jexl2

```
public enum Gender { MALE, FEMALE};

public static void main( String[] args ) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    JexlEngine jexl = new JexlEngine();
    Record r = new Record();
    r.setHeader(new RecordHeader());
    JexlContext jc = new MapContext();
    jc.set("r", r );
    jc.set("com.sytrue.objects.Gender", Gender.class );
    Expression e = jexl.createExpression( "r.header.gender=com.sytrue.objects.Gender.FEMALE" );
    System.out.println( e.evaluate(jc) );
}
```

but under jexl3 it throws an exception:

```
public static void main( String[] args ) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    JexlEngine jexl = new JexlBuilder().create();
    Record r = new Record();
    r.setHeader(new RecordHeader());
    JexlContext jc = new MapContext();
    jc.set("r", r );
    jc.set("com.sytrue.objects.Gender", Gender.class );
    JexlExpression e = jexl.createExpression( "r.header.gender=com.sytrue.objects.Gender.FEMALE" );
    System.out.println( e.evaluate(jc) );
}
```

The exception is:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.commons.jexl3.JexlException$Property: com.sytrue.objects.record.app.JexlTestApp.main@1:42 unsolvable property 'FEMALE'
```

I made it to work using the valueOf method:

```
JexlExpression e = jexl.createExpression( "r.header.gender=com.sytrue.objects.Gender.valueOf('FEMALE')" );
```

It seems that I no longer can access the enum type in jexl3.
Is there any reason this doesn't work anymore or it is a bug

Answer (score 0):

It turns out it was a bug:
I posted this question on JIRA:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/JEXL-191
It will be fixed in version 3.1